# Identifying use case diagram elements

Tags: use-case, user-stories

To map the User Stories, Epics, and Roles to Use Case diagram elements what are the possible methods of we can follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my optinion there is no close relationship between use case diagrams and user stories that would justify any kind of automation or formal process. (Epics and roles are even further off in terms of relationship.)

- A user story describes requirements, seen from the customers perspective.
- A use case diagram describes the predicted behaviour of a system,
  including all possible outcomes.

That being said, I believe you should develop user stories and use case diagrams separately. As you cannot easily transform one into the other you will have to put in double effort to create both in good quality.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding.
Epic - You can say in epic is the Requirement folder in which several requirement can assigned. In short Epic is the collection of large/smaller user stories.
User story - It is basically a requirement.

You can map User story with Epic.
But mapping with use case diagram is a separate activity.